# Migrating Java WEB, ZK, Spring project from non Maven to Maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, java-7, zk

I am migrating to Maven , on Netbeans, an old project based on Java 1.7 that runs on glassfish 3, the project uses Hibernate 4.3.1, Spring 3.0.6, and ZK 6 for the interface part.

I managed to add all the former jars to the POM.xml  I also created the beans.xml file. So the project compiles without errors, the project also starts ok and the first page ( the login page ) opens correctly. In the logs I can see all the database access working fine, so the domains and businessImpl are also running fine, but when I loggin, the page that should load fails to show with the following error :

```
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[zkLoader]: Servlet.service() for servlet zkLoader threw exception
java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at org.zkoss.bind.xel.zel.PathELResolver.getValue(PathELResolver.java:54)
    at org.zkoss.zel.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.zkoss.xel.zel.XelELResolver.getValue(XelELResolver.java:72)
    at org.zkoss.bind.xel.zel.BindELResolver.getValue(BindELResolver.java:75)
    at org.zkoss.zel.impl.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at org.zkoss.zel.impl.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.zkoss.xel.zel.ELXelExpression.evaluate(ELXelExpression.java:40)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BindEvaluatorXImpl.getValue(BindEvaluatorXImpl.java:43)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.LoadPropertyBindingImpl.load(LoadPropertyBindingImpl.java:58)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.PropertyBindingHandler.doLoadBinding(PropertyBindingHandler.java:171)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.PropertyBindingHandler.doLoad(PropertyBindingHandler.java:372)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.loadComponentProperties(BinderImpl.java:1804)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.loadComponent(BinderImpl.java:1781)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer$BinderKeeper$Loader.load(BindComposer.java:468)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer$BinderKeeper.loadComponentForAllBinders(BindComposer.java:450)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer.doAfterCompose(BindComposer.java:174)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doAfterCompose(UiEngineImpl.java:529)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:824)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.createComponents(UiEngineImpl.java:1024)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents0(AbstractExecution.java:246)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents(AbstractExecution.java:238)
    at org.zkoss.zul.Include.afterCompose(Include.java:448)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:822)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:741)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:701)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:394)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:316)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:214)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After adding additional logs to the ZK ViewModel of the page not loading I could determine that the error occurs just after the init() of the ViewModel, it means when ZK tries to evaluate information to be displayed, like in a @bind or @load. This explains why the login page loads, it is a static page not displaying dinamic information.

So in the migration I must have missed someting that allows ZK and Srping to inter-actuate ?

I expect that in the migration i missed some config file for Spring or ZK but only based on the error shown above my friend Google was not of much help...
Any suggestion on where to look at?

EDIT : 
Thanks Hawk ! thanks to your comments I managed to identify a little more the origin of the issue. I removed the full content of the home page and it loaded, of course, then re-inserting whichever component one by one i got the same error, so basicaly, any @load or @bind triggers this error. Now as this application is quite old, I had some pages that were originally develloped in ZK5,  without view models (ie: without apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" in the zul, but with  "use="ui.Class" in the ZK window header), so without any @load or @bind in the zul, those pages work perfect. So the issue is definitelly that ZK 6 is not managing to @load or @bind anything. It is a global configuration issue due to my incorrect migration to MAVEN.

EDIT2:
Migrate project to IntelliJ, with MAVEN, and same issue, compiles, run, but ZK pages including @Load or @Bind generate same error...

```
java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at org.zkoss.bind.xel.zel.PathELResolver.getValue(PathELResolver.java:54)
    at org.zkoss.zel.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.zkoss.xel.zel.XelELResolver.getValue(XelELResolver.java:72)
    at org.zkoss.bind.xel.zel.BindELResolver.getValue(BindELResolver.java:75)
    at org.zkoss.zel.impl.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at org.zkoss.zel.impl.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.zkoss.xel.zel.ELXelExpression.evaluate(ELXelExpression.java:40)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BindEvaluatorXImpl.getValue(BindEvaluatorXImpl.java:43)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.LoadPropertyBindingImpl.load(LoadPropertyBindingImpl.java:58)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.PropertyBindingHandler.doLoadBinding(PropertyBindingHandler.java:171)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.PropertyBindingHandler.doLoad(PropertyBindingHandler.java:372)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.loadComponentProperties(BinderImpl.java:1804)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.loadComponent(BinderImpl.java:1781)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer$BinderKeeper$Loader.load(BindComposer.java:468)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer$BinderKeeper.loadComponentForAllBinders(BindComposer.java:450)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer.doAfterCompose(BindComposer.java:174)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doAfterCompose(UiEngineImpl.java:529)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:824)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.createComponents(UiEngineImpl.java:1024)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents0(AbstractExecution.java:246)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents(AbstractExecution.java:238)
    at org.zkoss.zul.Include.afterCompose(Include.java:448)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:822)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:816)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:741)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:701)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:394)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:316)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:214)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, it's related to resolving data binding expressions. If you can locate which expression cause the error, it would be helpful. You can remove data binding one by one until you find the problematic one.

Comment: Would it help if I posted the web.xml, applicationContext.xml and the dispatcher-servlet.xml ? They are fine for the non-maven project but maybe they have to be edited when running in Maven context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found, the issue coming from the EL binding anotations from ZK, I checked the pom.xml for the versions and found inconsistency. Even if the non maven project runs fine with the zk libraries versions as they were specified in the pom, i changed the ZKEL dependency to a more recent one and it worked. thanks Hawk for putting me on rigth track.

Answer (score 1):

You should add ZK related jars with the same version e.g. zkmax, zul, zk, and zel. Since you use Maven, if you just specify zkmax or zkex, Maven will automatically include the same version of dependencies (if you don't override it).

Please refer to https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Setting_up_IDE/Maven/Resolving_ZK_Framework_Artifacts_via_Maven#ZK_EE